# Rendering a DisplayActionSheet with ObservableCollection data in Xamarin Cross platform app

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am building a new BLE app in Xamarin, using the [Monkey.Robotics](http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/monkey.robotics) component from Xamarin. I am using this [Heart Rate](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/BluetoothHeartRateMonitor) sample as a starting point. However, I want a *dashboard* type homepage, where received characteristics are displayed. Then I want an *"add device"* button at the bottom, which triggers the scanning and pairing procedure.

I currently have an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%601/) class set up to add all devices found into a list view. I would really like to have all of the functionality on one page, so that I don't complicate the different states, for "have previously paired", "want to pair a new device" and "haven't ever paired". I would ideally like to use a [DisplayActionSheet](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/pop-ups/).

This is the given example

```
var actionButton1 = new Button { Text = "ActionSheet Simple" };
actionButton1.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
    var action = await DisplayActionSheet ("ActionSheet: Send to?", "Cancel", null, "Email", "Twitter", "Facebook");
    Debug.WriteLine("Action: " + action); // writes the selected button label to the console
 };
```

Is it possible for me to populate this with the dynamic data coming from the scan through the *ObservableCollection*?

Here is my current arrangement:

```
this.devices = new ObservableCollection<IDevice> ();
listView.ItemsSource = devices;

adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (object sender, DeviceDiscoveredEventArgs e) => {
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        devices.Add (e.Device);
    });
};
```

Suggestions for how I might achieve this would be really appreciated (and whether it is possible, or there is a better way of doing this?), whilst still keeping to the correct structure for the DisplayActionSheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DisplayActionSheet` accepts `params string[] list`, so the following structure works!

```
actionButton1.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
    var action = await DisplayActionSheet ("ActionSheet: Send to?", "Cancel", null, this.devices.Select(device => device.Name).ToArray());
     // map action back to IDevice
     // ...
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

DisplayActionSheet.

LCA is a model type list CausasModel

```
var LCA = await ca.ListaCausas();
string causa = await DisplayActionSheet("Lista de Causas", "Cancelar", "Ok", (string[])LCA.Select(x => x.Nombre.ToString()).ToArray());
txtCausas.Text=causa;
```